# Can someone explain how this program is working? It displays the binary equivalent of a number through a recursive function

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int binary(int);

void main()
{
    int num;    
    printf("Enter the number:\n");
    scanf_s("%d", &num);
    binary(num);
}

int binary(int num)
{
    int rem;
    rem = num % 2;
    num = num / 2;
    if(num == 0)
    {
        printf("\nThe binary equivalent is %d", rem);
        return rem;
    }
    else
        binary(num);
    printf("%d", rem);
}
```

I am not able to understand the working of return statement here. To what does it return the value to? I want to know how the final output is coming. Say if we take '8' as input, it outputs 1000, which is the binary equivalent of '8'. But I am unable to get the working.

Comment: Step through the code in a debugger or work out the numbers using pencil and paper. That will help you a lot.

Comment: In this code no one use the return value.

Comment: It returns the numer but doesn't use the return value - the code is still UB though, as you are missing a return statement at the end of the function

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying to explain step by step.

```
int num;
printf("Enter the number:\n");
scanf("%d",&num);
```

This code taking a decimal number from user. And then calling a function `binary(num);`

In `binary(num)` function:

```
int binary(int num)
{
    int rem;
    rem=num%2;
    num=num/2;
    if(num==0)
    {
        printf("\nThe binary equivalent is %d",rem);
        return rem;
    }
    else
        binary(num);
    printf("%d",rem);
}
```

Firstly you must know how to make a number from `decimal` to `binary`. In this `recursive` function that work has done.

```
if(num==0)
```

means if the num is zero then it will terminate and return the binary value that is `rem`. We are storing binary value in the `rem`.

else it will be continue and calling the function `binary()` again to calculate the rest of the number.

Answer (score 0):

Im assuming you are not very familiar with how recursion works so Ill write it out here. :)

Example of input = 8. We run the function `binary(8)`.

Start with `binary(8)`: `rem = 8%2 = 0`, `num = 8/2 = 4`. Since `num` is not `0`, run `binary(4)`. Note that after `binary(4)` finishes, we will need to print `rem`  which is `0`. But now, we need to run `binary(4)` first.

Run `binary(4)`: `rem = 4%2 = 0`, `num = 4/2 = 2`. Since `num` is not `0`, run `binary(2)`. Again, we will print `rem` which is `0` after the function `binary(2)` finishes. But now, we need to run `binary(2)` first.

Run `binary(2)`: `rem = 2%2 = 0`, `num = 2/2 = 1`. Since `num` is still not `0`, run `binary(1)`. Again, we will print `rem` which is `0` after the function `binary(1)` finishes. But now, we need to run `binary(1)` first.

Run `binary(1)`: `rem = 1%2 = 1`, `num = 1/2 = 0`(integer division). Since `num` is finally `0` (this is what we call a `base case` for `recursion`), we print `"\nThe binary equivalent is 1`.

--We start returning back to the previous functions--

Now that `binary(1)` finishes, we are return back to `binary(2)` to finish up the remaining statements *(refer to above)*. Thus we print `0`. Then `binary(2)` finishes.

Now that `binary(2)` finishes, we return back to `binary(4)` to finish up the remaining statements *(refer to above)*. Thus we print `0` again. Then `binary(4)` finishes.

Now that `binary(4)` finishes, we return back to `binary(8)` to finish up the remaining statements *(refer to above)*. Thus we print `0`. Then finally `binary(8)` finishes.

Finally, the output is: `\n The binary equivalent is 1000`

Oh ya, btw your `binary` function can be a `void` function. Since it doesnt return any useful values.